# How do you add numbers or letters to the filenames in a folder in python?

Tags: python, addition, strip

I made a program using the strip method in Python to remove the letters from filenames.  I would like to know if there is a function that can do the opposite thing in Python?  For example if I have a list of files whose names have no numbers in front of them, how can python add numbers to the front of them.  This is the code that I have. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated. I am using Python 3.6

```
import os
def rename_files():
    #(1) get files names from a folder
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Keith\Desktop\prank")
    print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print (saved_path)
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Keith\Desktop\prank")

    #2 rename all files names in folder
    for file_name in file_list:
        print ("Old Name - " +file_name)
        print ("New Name - " +file_name.strip("0123456789"))
        os.rename(file_name,file_name.strip("0123456789"))
    os.chdir(saved_path)

rename_files()
```

Comment: [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) will help.

Comment: ```'0' + 'abc'``` or ```''.join(('0', 'abc'))```